# Passing objects via clusterExport or as function arguments

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rparallel

Is it more efficient to pass objects to `parallel::parLapply` and `parallel::parLapplyLB` as function arguments or to export them with `parallel::clusterExport`? I.e.

```
parallel::parLapply(cl, 1:1000, function(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) {
  ...
}, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
```

or

```
parallel::clusterExport(cl, c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"))
parallel::parLapply(cl, 1:1000, function(y) {
  ...
})
```

Non parallel functions e.g. do by default not make copies of the arguments passed to them. They only create copies when the objects are modified. I was wondering, whether the two above mentioned parallel options were differently good at avoiding unnecessary object copies.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? To share data you need `makeCluster` to be able to `FORK` the processes. Unfortunately, [Windows only allows PSOCK](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/06/parallel-r-socket-or-fork/), meaning that the data will anyway be copied to each worker, making little difference between the two options you consider.

Comment: I am using a Windows machine and consequently `PSOCK`. Even though it copies the data in that case, do the two approaches mentioned in the question handle it with different efficiency? And what about the `FORK` case? Which option would be more efficient with a `FORK` cluster?

Answer (score 1):

For the large data set with both of your versions, I experienced memory management difficulties. I can suggest:

```
par_func <- function(my_list, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, ncores){
  # A function to use in the parallel loop
  loop_fun <- function(x){
    # x is i. element in the list
    tryCatch({
      foo(x, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) # the actual function which would do the work
    }, error = function(err){
      #error_case <- foo2(x, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) # in case something goes wrong foo2 will deliver something
      error_case <- NULL  # or it can also just return NA or NULL instead of a function's output to prevent error
      return(error_case)
      })
  }
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(ncores)
  x1 <- x1
  x2 <- x2
  x3 <- x3 
  x4 <- x4 
  x5 <- x5
  out <- parallel::parSapplyLB(cl = cl, 
                               X = my_list,
                               FUN = function(x) loop_fun(x)
                               )
  return(out)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further on your answer? It appears to not really answer my question. `x1 <- x1`, `x2 <- x2` etc. has no effect on the function. Reassigning objects after calling `makeCluster` does not export them to the workers. The reason why `loop_fun` can be called without passing `x1` to `x5` as arguments is that the function is defined within `par_func`.

Comment: I am awarding the bounty because calling a named function rather than generating an anonymous one inside `parSapply` does actually speed up the outer function. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: x1 <- x1, x2 <- x2, x3 <- x3, x4 <- x4, x5 <- x5 I add this to make sure that these variables are available in function's environment. But you can remove it.